# How not to forget to add files

Tags: git, repository

I situation that often occurs for me is :

- I create a new file
- I modify an existing file

Everything compiles, I'm proud of myself.

- I commit
- I push it to the server

My teammates pull : They can't compile because a file is missing.
They all want to kill me.

The question is, how to make sure I've added all needed files?

Comment: To be sure: you don't ask about how to amend a commit but on how to forget adding, right ?

Comment: yes, How to **not** forget adding

Comment: I always do `git status` before pushing, to make sure I did not miss anything in the "to add" file list

Comment: Look at the list of untracked files. git-ignore everything that needs to be ignored. After that, there should not be too many files left. If there are, clean up your workspace...

Comment: @fedorqui An additional warning on commit that a file is missing could be interesting, though.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087143/how-can-you-git-add-a-new-file-without-staging-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956522/git-commit-auto-add-new-folders-or-files

Comment: I'm not sure those "related" questions are relevant here.

Comment: git commit will show you if there are untracked files. That should be a warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always do `git status` before pushing, to make sure I did not miss anything in the "to add" file list.

The output is quite explanatory:

```
$ git status
On branch XXX
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   YYY

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ZZZ1
    ZZZ2
```

Then, it is also good to have some kind of `staging` environment that is shared with everyone. This way, when you push you also make sure the `staging` environment is also stable, so others will have a working example of your recent changes:

```
$ git checkout staging
$ git pull --rebase
$ git merge <your_branch>
$ git push
```

Answer (score 8):

As a best practice you should always check `git status` before committing.

You can modify any of the git hooks (pre-commit, post-commit) to print out to screen list of your untracked files so you will see it and wont miss it.

use this command to print out untracked files:

`git ls-files --others --exclude-standard`

Another solution:
you can write an alias that does it for you as well so you will not forget to do it next time.

#### Nice to have:

set your color settings to display your changes in color, meaning

- red - deleted files
- green - added files
- magenta - modified files

So it will be easier for you to track changes.

Comment: What would be interesting is to use that to prepend the list to the commented message you get in the commit message editor but I don't know if the commit template can serve this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I like to have my bash prompt warn me if I have a dirty state and which branch I'm working on.

```
/tmp/myrepo (master) $ touch newfile.txt
/tmp/myrepo (master %) $ git add newfile.txt 
/tmp/myrepo (master +) $ git commit -m 'added newfile'
[master 9fe6399] added newfile
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 newfile.txt
/tmp/myrepo (master) $
```

This is achieved by adding the following to .bashrc

```
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
export GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=true
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;33m\]\w\[\033[01;32m\]$(__git_ps1) \[\033[01;36m\]$ \[\033[00m\]'
```